# wrong mstest.exe on the build server

Tags: c#, build

How do i use the correct Mstest.exe in the Build?

My configuration:

- TFS2012
- VS2010

Then I installed :

- VS2012
- VS2012 update3
- VS2010 service pack 1
- Team Explorer 2012 (busy installing)

On Build Compile is succesfull, when testing msbuild "hangs" ...

I want to use VS2012 mstest (11.0) and not the VS2010(10.0)

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe

instead of

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe

This causes the build to hang.  When executing the 11.0\mstest.exe on the build server it is working correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the Build File where you can specify the path for mstest in a parameter, I called it MStestFolder.

**The folder property**

```
<x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="MStestFolder" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
</x:Members>
```

3 times i had to specify the toolpath for mstest

**Mstest tag**

```
<mtbwa:MSTest .... ToolPath="[MStestFolder]" .../>
```

In the Build you have to specify the MStestFolder in the Misc tab :)