# Unable to use MsTest(VS 2015) for running tests(vsmdi) migrated from VS 2010

Tags: c#, tfs, mstest

We are doing migration of our solution(including test projects) from VS 2010 to VS 2015.
TFS server version is 2013.
Build server have VS 2015 and VS 2010 versions installed. 
Issue is that every time i run the build, MSTest.exe that gets used for running the tests is:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
```

But i want `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"` to be used.

I checked `vsmdi` file and Build definition in TFS, But they don't seem to have an option to change MSTest.exe path.
Is it possible to change MsTest path that the build server uses?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using mstest.exe any longer in Visual Studio. You should be using vstest.console.exe to run your tests.  I am not sure how that interacts with a vsmdi file, so I can't give you a proper answer on how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

> You'll need to change the build template's **MSTest activity** which
>   may be located in several locations depending on your template. In the
>   default template the activity is labelled "Run MSTest for Metadata
>   File" or "Run MSTest for Test Assembly".
>
> Go to it's properties and change the ToolPath to `C":\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"`.
>
> If it wasn't there
>   before, you had to ADD the **ToolPaath** tag  `ToolPath="C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe`

More details please refer  *lordkain's* answer and in this question [wrong mstest.exe on the build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632782/wrong-mstest-exe-on-the-build-server)